# How can I get the address of initializer?

Tags: c++

The code below introduces a class C. The class has constructor, copy constructor, operator= and one member. How can I get the address of the object created by C(2) in the function main()?

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    int a;

    C(const C &other)
    {   
        std::cout << "Copy Constructor:" << a << std::endl;
    }   

    C(int a)
    {   
        this->a = a;
        std::cout << "Constructor:" << a << std::endl;
    }   

    C &operator=(const C &other)
    {   
        std::cout << "operator=:this.a = " << a << " | other.a = " << other.a << std::endl;
        a = other.a;
        return *this;
    }   

    ~C()
    {   
        std::cout << "Destructor:" << a << std::endl;
    }   
};

    int main()
    {
        C a(1);

        a = C(2);
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You are forbidden from taking addresses of temporaries. They will go out of scope very quickly, leaving you with an invalid address.

Comment: Agreed. You can hack it with http://pastebin.com/ufGtBZ9Y but as you can see, the d-tor will be called immediately after the assignment and you will still need to compile with -fpermissive or the compiler won't let you do this.

Comment: Can you please point me to an authorative source that confirms your statemets? Also do you mean that this temporary object can disappear before closing }?

Comment: Here you can see the code with the destruction order: http://pastebin.com/fvTEycTb

Comment: @RomanB: In this case, my gcc is my authorative source (with its error saying `error: taking address of temporary`). And yes, a temporary object can disappear before the end of its enclosing block.

Comment: @RomanB.: even more interestingly, in various shady circumstances the lifetime of temporaries can be _extended_ - this is the exception (see § 12.2 "Temporary objects", sub 4 and 5). Really fun stuff to read. C++ is full of surprises

Comment: @RomanB.: it is yours ([n3242.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), the latest working draft, which has been promoted into the standard _without changes_ ([WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)) and various members of the standards committee are on record over this fact).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a helper function to write the address somewhere before the object goes out of scope:

```
template <typename T>
T const & store_possibly_invalid_address(T const & t, T const *& p)
{
    p = &t;
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    C a(1);
    C const * invalid_address;
    a = store_possibly_invalid_address(C(2), invalid_address);

    // The temporary is out of scope, but you can see where it was.
    // Don't dereference the pointer.
}
```

That could be educational, to discover where the compiler chooses to put temporaries. It has no purpose in any real code, though.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is with some collaboration inside the class; the
constructor has the address (the `this` pointer), and can put it
somewhere where you can get at it later.  I'd recommend against it,
though, since the object won't live long enough for you to do much with
it.  (On the other hand, it's sometimes useful for debugging to output 
it.)